# How to set a variable at runtime in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

The whole goal of what I am trying to do, is to become root user and run a process. However, I created a process that, I call a auxiliary host and run a script that grabs the root password for whichever Linux host I want. After that, I pass the password back to the var `ansible_become_password:`. Though every time I pass it, it throws the error "`password is undefined`.

I looked up the variable precedence, but when I tried a different way, I received the same error.

**Code:**

```
# Root
- name: Run as root user. privileged escalation using su
  hosts: 10.x.x.1
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    root_user: root
    ansible_become_password: "{{ password.stdout }} "

  tasks:   
    - name: Get root password
      shell: /tmp/rootAccess.sh hostname
      register: password

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ password.stdout }}"
        delegate_to: 10.x.x.2


    - name: whoami as root (su)
      command: whoami
      register: output_root_su
      become_user: "{{ root_user }}"
      become_method: su
      become: yes

    - name: output of 'whoami' (su)
      debug:
        msg: "user: {{ output_root_su.stdout }} "
```

**Error:**

```
fatal: [10.x.x.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The field 'become_pass' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'password' is undefined"}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to declare *ansible_become_password* with the module *set_fact* after the password was entered.

The play below

```yaml
    - hosts: test_01
      gather_facts: no
      become: no
      remote_user: admin

      vars:
        root_user: root
        # ansible_become_password: "{{ password.user_input }}"

      tasks:
        - command: whoami
          register: result
        - debug:
            var: result.stdout
        - pause:
            prompt: "Enter password"
          register: password
        - set_fact:
            ansible_become_password: "{{ password.user_input }}"
        - debug:
            var: ansible_become_password
        - command: whoami
          register: result
          become: yes
          become_method: su
          become_user: "{{ root_user }}"
        - debug:
            var: result.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
    PLAY [test_01] *********************************************************************************************
    
    TASK [command] *********************************************************************************************
    changed: [test_01]
    
    TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************
    ok: [test_01] => {
        "result.stdout": "admin"
    }
    
    TASK [pause] ***********************************************************************************************
    [pause]
    Enter password:
    [[ok: [test_01]
    
    TASK [set_fact] ********************************************************************************************
    ok: [test_01]
    
    TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************
    ok: [test_01] => {
        "ansible_become_password": "password"
    }
    
    TASK [command] *********************************************************************************************
    changed: [test_01]
    
    TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************
    ok: [test_01] => {
        "result.stdout": "root"
    }
    
    PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************
    test_01                    : ok=7    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Notes

- [Lazy Evaluation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html) does not work properly with *ansible_become_password*, obviously.
- Module [pause](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pause_module.html#pause-pause-playbook-execution) provides a convenient method to enter variables at runtime.
- There is an extra space before the closing quote. This would render the password wrong.

```yaml
ansible_become_password: "{{ password.stdout }} "
```