# Is it possible to add a password to the "become: true" method in a Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-vault

I have a question regarding the use of `become: true`.

I have been researching for a while if there is a way to run the tasks as `sudo`. I don't want to give `-k -K` when I run the playbook or something like that.

My playbook should run automatically with a pipeline and that's why I can't use that. I have a vault where my encrypted passwords are. I can output my password in clear text like this:

```yaml
- name: test1 
  ansible.builtin.debug: 
    msg: "{{ passwords.user_sudo_rights }}"
```

I would like something for example so

```yaml
- hosts: all 
  become: true 
  become_password: "{{ passwords.user_sudo_rights }}"
```

to become sudo with a password.

I have also tried the variant with the `/vars/group_vars.yml` but it does not work either.

```yaml
ansible_become: true 
ansible_become_method: sudo 
ansible_become_pass: "{{ user_sudo_rights }}"
```

I am not allowed by company policy to use passwordless sudo

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. We have for example no idea how and where you set the `passwords` or `user_sudo_rights` variable prior to using them. We don't know either what is the exact result of running the above code (an error, an unexpected result...). Note that `/vars/group_vars.yml` is not automatically loaded by ansible for anything. I suspect what you are after is `group_vars/all.yml` for the `all` group by placing that directory next to your inventory and/or next to your playbook.

Comment: Does [How to set a variable a runtime in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57104529/6771046) answer your question?